# Scroll fast with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` which I autoscroll via

```
  // First the timer is called.  
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:scrollerTimerInterval
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(_autoScrollTimerMethod)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
      - (void) _autoScrollTimerMethod{
        scrollerTimerCount++;
        CGFloat offset = scrollerTimerCount * 1;
        uiWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offset);
 }
```

uiWebView is of type `UIWebView`

This code does autoscroll the uiWebView, but its too slow.  There is a flicker in another part of the program which does not occur when this code is commented out.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Cheers,

Comment: scrollerTimerInterval is set to...?

Comment: It varies depending on the page size but around 0.04.  Even when I put it to 4 seconds, it works normal for a bit then it starts to flicker.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to interact with it while this auto-scrolling is happening?

Comment: Sorry for your time, but I found the problem.  It was not in the code above.  In the delegate function scrollViewDidScroll I had the line [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1] and when I removed it this now works.   Thanks for you guys help.  Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think I came up with a solution that might do what you need.  Basically, I created a UIWebView inside of a UIScrollView.  I had to do this, because otherwise the UIWebView by itself wouldn't be fully rendered why the animation is going, and you would get large sections of white (unrendered portions of the webview).  So in Interface Builder, add a scrolview with a webview inside it, then hook them both up to IBOutlets.

You'll also need your ViewController to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

In your viewDidLoad, (or interface builder) hook up the delegate for the webview:

```
    self.webView.delegate = self;
```

Then load a URL in the webview:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"]]];
```

Once the webview is finished loading, we will expand it's frame to the full height of the contentSize, causing it to be fully rendered.  No this will be a memory hob if you do this for very large web pages, so use it with caution.  Then we will set the contentSize of the scrollview to match, then simply animate setting the content offset to the end, with whatever duration you want.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

   webView.frame = CGRectMake(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    self.scrollView.contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```